# Defining a General Complex Number

Tags: complex, variable-definitions

I am trying to compute the Complex conjugate of two complex numbers multiplied together. However, when I go to define my complex numbers as $a+b I$ and $c+dI$ it does not like $b$ and $d$ because they are complex. I have tried to use `Assumptions`, but it also does not like that. Any ideas on how to define a and b to be real numbers?

```
z1 = a + b I, Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals
```

Ideally what I would like is to have something of form

```
Simplify[Conjugate[z1 z2], {a,b,c,d} \[Element] Reals] \\Expand
```

which is what worked, but what does the \Expand part do? I know it expands it out but why the \ attached to it? What does that do to it?

Comment: `Collect[(a + b j) (c + d j), j] /. j -> -I`

Comment: you are right. Now I would like to be able to define a and b as real numbers

Comment: "define a and b as real numbers"? Mathematica isn't  typed language...

Comment: See also [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Comment: As for your last question, \\`Expand` is bad syntax. Probably you meant `// Expand`. In order to understand what `//` is, highlight it and hit F1.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Assumptions` can be used in general like this

### Method 1

First let us define the general list of reals

```
$Assumptions = {(a|b|c|d) \[Element] Reals}
```

Now you can check that it works.

```
Simplify[Conjugate[(a + b I) (c + d I)]]
(*(a - I b) (c - I d)*)
```

### Method 2

Instead of defining all your variables separately, you can in fact define a real array and use the array elements as your variable

Here t is the real array

```
  $Assumptions = {(t[_]) \[Element] Reals}
```

Then you can use the array elements `t`

```
  Simplify[Conjugate[(t[1] + t[2] I) (t[3] + t[4] I)]]
  (*(t[1] - I t[2]) (t[3] - I t[4])*)
```

### Method 3

I'm not sure if this is a good practice but it seems that I can make everything to be real like this

```
 $Assumptions = {(_) \[Element] Reals}
```

Answer (score 2):

How simple is this?

```
Conjugate[(a + b I) (c + d I)] // ComplexExpand
a c - b d + I (-b c - a d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions can not be used in general. It is specific to certain functions such as `Simplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate` ... as explained in the document [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html?q=Assumptions)

In order to get the desired result use:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[(a + b I) (c + d I)],
 Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals && d ∈ Reals]
```

For `Simplify` the second argument is the assumptions so you don't have to specify that explicity.

```
Simplify[Conjugate[(a + b I) (c + d I)],
 a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && c ∈ Reals && d ∈ Reals]
```

Comment: When I use that, my output is (c - I d) (a + Conjugate[bI])

Comment: @JackArmstrong - If you are getting `Conjugate[bI]`, you left out the space or asterisk between `b` and `I`

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way:

```
z1 = a + I*b;
z2 = c + I*d;

expr = Simplify[z1*z2 // Conjugate, {a, b, c, d} \[Element] Reals] // 
  Expand

(*  a c - I b c - I a d - b d  *)
```

Then like this:

```
(expr /. Complex[0, -1] -> 0) + Factor[expr - (expr /. Complex[0, -1] -> 0)]

(*  a c - b d - I (b c + a d)   *)
```

Alternatively, like this:

```
expr[[1]] + expr[[4]] + Factor[Take[expr[[2 ;; 3]]]]

(*  a c - b d - I (b c + a d)   *)
```

But if you claim that it is uncomfortable not to have a simple function for this kind of things, I agree.

Have fun!